# How to upgrade numpy in Blender from command line?

Tags: python

I am trying to upgrade the numpy (1.11.2 to 1.17.4) in my Blender 2.79, because I have an addon script that requires higher than numpy >= 1.13). I know that Blender 2.8 has a more recent version of numpy, but the custom script has not been developed for Blender 2.8 yet.

So, I have to upgrade the numpy that is in

`/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.79/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` (where it is located on a fresh install).

One line of code I tried was:

`pip install--install-option="--prefix$/Applications/Blender/belnder.app/Contents/Resources/2.79/python/lib/python3.5" numpy --upgrade`

but then I get the error:

`ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

How can I successfully upgrade the numpy package within Blender's python?

Alternatively,

When I amend the path in sys.path to the python I normally use (sys.path *only* contains '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/' and '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/'), which contains a higher version of numpy than that included in blender, and I try to import numpy, I then get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.5 from "/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.4" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?